# Mule ESB Volumetric Reporting

Tags: mule, monitoring, mule-component

I would like to provide a daily report showing, for the various Mule Flows deployed, message volumes (hourly or user defined) and average processing for the period defined. The data used in the report should be in a simple format, csv or similar, so that it can be loaded into Excel or a database.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how best to achieve the above - either tools I can use to capture the data myself, or even packaged monitoring products. The MMC is ok, but it only shows totals (or averages based on the totals), plus the data cannot be exported (easily).

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider activating [Business events](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Business+Events) with default event tracking?
This will put all this information plus more in a database, the only trade off is that you have to maintain that database to not to occupy all disk space, etc.

Comment: Hi Victor - Yes, I use Business Events, but while its good for diagnostics, e.g. check whether a specific message processed and at what time etc, Business Events are not much use for analytics, e.g. show the volume of messages over the course of a day broken down by Mule Flow and hour.

Comment: I need to check but I believe Business Events with default event tracking should be able to give you pretty much a message per every single event started on an inbound endpoint with no more changes than setting the event trackint to true. Then you can go to the database and with the proper query extract the information you want.

Comment: I think you're probably correct Victor. I've never used H2 databases before, but have installed the console app and am now trying to come to grips with accessing the db...thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You don't need to use H2 necessarily, you could potentially configure PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL or MS SQL Server: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Persisting+MMC+Data+On+External+Databases

Answer (score 0):

In our case we're using Elastic Stack (ES, Logstash and Kibana) for this purpose. More info in https://www.elastic.co/v5

We use logstash for getting Mule logs to ES. You can track almost everything from Flows logs.

It's obviously with Business Events.